# Check all boxes toggle method not working like expected

Tags: angularjs

I'm wiriting a method to toggle a checklist as checked / unchecked, as follow:

```
$scope.checkAllToggle = function(dtProvider, destiny, ev) {
    $(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('span').html());
        data[destiny] = [];
        if ($(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('span').html()=='Check all') {
            for (var val in data[dtProvider]) data[destiny].push(data[dtProvider][val].id);
            $(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('span').html('Uncheck all');
        }
        else $(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('span').html('Check all');

    }
```

The label of the toggle button changes every time, but the state of the checkboxs only becomes checked after 2 click, from this point change in each 3 clicks.
What's wrong?

Append

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
```

to the method make no difference, as prepending $scope to data

Code in plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Zf6UzLbC4osRov7IR5Na?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Rather than do it that way, this would be the easier way to do it.

Make the master input and assign it to a model.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="master">
```

Then have your other inputs be tied to the master like this.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="box1" ng-checked="master">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="box2" ng-checked="master">
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="box3" ng-checked="master">
```

Here is your plunker with these changes.
[Master Checkbox Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i6r7IooIydWa4PPPjYBn?p=preview)

Comment: Yes, but you are not using the facilities of `checklist-model`

Comment: Do you have to use checklist-model? Its a fairly simple directive to implement a checkbox group if that is all you need.

Comment: Because the checklist must be dinamic

Comment: have you looked at my solution below, It maintains your reliance on checklist-model, and also solves your UI display issues.

Answer (score 0):

I got your plunker to work by doing this.

```
$scope.checkToggle = function(dtProvider, destiny, ev) {
  $scope.data[destiny] = [];
  if ($(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('span').html() == 'Check all') {
    for (var val in $scope.data[dtProvider]){
      $scope.data[destiny].push($scope.data[dtProvider][val].id);
      $(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('span').html('Uncheck all');        
    }
  } else {
    $(ev.currentTarget).parent().find('span').html('Check all');
  }
  $scope.$apply(); 
};
```

I could not get it to work if calling safely like if(!$scope.$$phase){$scope.$apply();} but it is working with straight $scope.$apply(). This might have something to do with rootScope and need to be safetly called in a different manner.

See this link: https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma

You also had some missing {} in your code that could have been causing some issues.